# RESTful Endpoint that returns single entity by two different unique parameters but not both at the same time

Tags: api, rest

I want to understand what would be the best way to represent this in a RESTful way, taking in consideration that the codebase it's a very large - inherited - legacy project and I have to add a lot of new functionality on top of it.

The API Definition is built with OpenaAPI3.

Let's take in consideration the following example:

`/v1/{customer}/types/{id}`

But the Types collection also has a database constraint of Unique(customer, code) - customer and code being columns from the Types table.

What I need to implement now is a new endpoint that will retrieve a single entity, based on the customer path param and code path param, without having to use the ID path param.

It's a matter of reducing the number of calls, that's why I don't want to make use of the ID path param also.

One solution would be to use query params:

`/v1/{customer}/types?code=123`

But this will basicaly return a Singleton List so it's not that trivial and definetley not a best practice.

What would be your take on this? I know I should have the ID in the place I want that entity to be returned, but this some case I want to get resovled without having to do another call to get the ID of the entity so I can call the initial endpoint.

Comment: This questions, in its current form, asks primarily for opinions rather than undisputable facts. I therefore voted to close it for its opinion-based nature. [Fielding](https://twitter.com/fielding/status/1052976631374000128?lang=en), the "inventor of REST", mentioned that REST does not have endpoints but resources. In general, the best advice to give in terms of designing such APIs is to model them as if you'd interact with a Web page and map these interaction steps to your domain. After all, REST is just Web surfing for applications